# excel - Delete cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. Trying to filter one column with value starts with 42 and 48 and delete rows, but there is error message 'Application defined or object defined error'. Can anyone help on this? Tq

```
Sub FilterDeleteVisible()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DO") 
    Call FilterAndDelete(ws, "E", "42*", "48*")    
End Sub

Sub FilterAndDelete(ws As Worksheet, col As String, ParamArray criteria() As Variant)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    MyArray = criteria
    Set rng = ws.Range(col & ":" & col)
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=MyArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: `rng` is a col. It is impossible to `.Offset(1, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

***Note:*** (Thanks for *@MGonet*'s comments)

- As wildcards are used, it only filters text and number as text. That is, it doesn' work for numbers in the column.
- `Operator:=xlFilterValues` doesn't support wildcards criterias. It is converted to `xlOr` if there are only two items (with wildcards) in `MyArray`.

```
rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=MyArray(0), Criteria1:=MyArray(1), Operator:=xlOr
```

---

- `rng` is a range object of Column. There isn't more space (cells) on worksheet for `rng.Offset(1, 0)`.
- Use `End(xlUp)` to get the last used cell on the column
- It's more reliable to resize range before using offset. `rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0)`
- `OERN` is used to ignore error when there isn't any visible rows after filtering.

```vb
Sub FilterAndDelete(ws As Worksheet, col As String, ParamArray criteria() As Variant)
    Dim rng As Range, lastRow As Long, c As Range
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    MyArray = criteria
    With ws
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, col), .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp))
    End With
    If UBound(MyArray) = 1 Then
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=MyArray(0), Criteria1:=MyArray(1), Operator:=xlOr
    Else
        ' Doesn't support wildcards if more than 2 items in MyArray
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=MyArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If
    On Error Resume Next 'OERN for blank
    Set c = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        c.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [End statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/end-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008904)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Two comments: 1) when using `xlFilterValues` you cannot use wildcards, 2) if there are 2 criteria you can use `xlOr` with wildcards providing that numbers are formatted as text, because wildcards cannot be used with numbers.

Comment: I don't agree with `xlFilterValues you cannot use wildcards`. I've tested it on Excel 365 w/o issues. I'll add a note to remind OP for it only filters the text contents.

Comment: As a general rule, you cannot use wildcards for the `xlFilterValues` criterion when there are 3 or more criteria in an array (they are treated like regular characters). However, if there are only two such criteria, VBA internally converts `xlFilterValues` to `xlOr` criterion and saves it that way. You can check how the filter criteria are saved.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

### Filter By Numbers With Wild Characters Using the Like Operator

- If your column contains numbers, `AutoFilter` won't work. Here's a workaround that'll be roughly as efficient as `Range.Union` will allow it.
- It will also work for strings but I guess using `AutoFilter` should be faster.
- It additionally allows you to have as many criteria as necessary.

**Usage**

```vb
Sub FilterDeleteVisible()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DO")
    FilterWcNumbers ws, "E", "42*", "48*"
End Sub
```

**The Method**

```vb
Sub FilterWcNumbers(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal Col As String, ParamArray Criteria() As Variant)
    
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns(Col))
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no column
    If rg.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub ' multiple columns
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count - 1
    If rCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no data in column
    
    Set rg = rg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
    
    Dim Data() As Variant
    
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(Criteria)
    
    Dim urg As Range, r As Long, c As Long
        
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 0 To cUpper
            If CStr(Data(r, 1)) Like Criteria(c) Then
                If urg Is Nothing Then
                    Set urg = rg.Cells(r)
                Else
                    Set urg = Union(urg, rg.Cells(r))
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
    If urg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no matches found
    
    urg.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp

End Sub
```